# Could not cast value of view controllers error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app was building fine until today when all of a sudden I got the following errors after a successful build:

```
Could not cast value of type 'FirebaseApp.HomeViewController' (0x101ab6aa0) to 'FirebaseApp.MenuViewController' (0x101ab6d30).


 Could not cast value of type 'FirebaseApp.HomeViewController' (0x101ab6aa0) to 'FirebaseApp.MenuViewController' (0x101ab6d30).
```

The line in my app delegate

> let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
>   "mainView") as! MenuViewController

was then highlighted red within this AppDelegate Class:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if user != nil {
            //
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController


            self.window?.rootViewController = controller
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {
            // main screen
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MenuViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = controller
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I have in my storyboard the mainView identified: [image]

And I have a HomeViewController

> class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

which has the bulk of my code.

I am not sure what went wrong here, but I suspect it has something to do with misnaming in my story board.

Edit: I solved this problem by changing "mainView" to "MenuViewController"

Comment: let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MenuViewController - this line returns you HomeViewController, but you forced type cast to MenuViewController, check your viewController identifiers in storyboard

Comment: Your screen shot shows a view, not a view controller. You're looking in the wrong place in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `storyboard` for `MenuViewController` you need to set `mainView` as `Storyboard ID` not the `Restoration ID`.

Like below image:

[image]